# JavaScript Algorithm Performance - Count the number of numbers in a range divisible by k

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, loops, time-complexity

I created an algorithm for finding the number of numbers inside a range that are divisible by a third number k. I got this to work but in polynomial time instead of linear time

```
function divisibleCount(x, y, k) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = x; i <= y; i++) {
        if (i % k === 0) {
            count++;
        }
    return count;
}
```

The arguments are as follows

```
x: Start of range
y: End of range
K: Number is divisible by
```

The problem is definitely the for loop which makes this polynomial time.

I attempted to use

```
for (var i = x; i <= k; i += k)
```

but got the wrong answer.

Is there any way I can improve this?

Comment: How a simple loop might cause polynomial time?

Comment: Since this works and you're looking for ways to improve it, this may be a a better candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com than here.

Comment: "but got the wrong answer." --- since you need to find the first number that is divisable by `k`, then divide what's left by `k` slices

Comment: I had the right answer when using ++ but not when trying to be more efficient

Comment: @zerkms - no need to find anything, just `%`.

Comment: @Amit "just `%`" - is how you find if a number is divisable by another number. I did not say one must use loops for that.

Comment: I'm just dying to know what the `y` argument is for ?

Comment: @zerkms and is also how you can *calculate* the first number, without looking for it.

Comment: @Amit that is indeed correct. "without looking for it" --- I did not suggest to use loops anywhere, not sure why you think I did.

Comment: Did you mean `i <= y`?

Comment: Find the number number of numbers between 0 and y divisible by k by dividing y by k and rounding down. Do the same thing for x, and subtract the second number from the first.

Comment: @zerkms I have been off by one since birth so I just fix it once I've coded it up :) *edit* probably should be between 1 and y, not zero.

Comment: Your working solution is `O(max(y-x, 0))` (assuming constant time for arithmetic operations). That's linear, not polynomial time. Regardless, you should be able to find the solution in constant time (`O(1)`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Faster algorithm to count how many numbers are divisible by a specific integer in a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777546/faster-algorithm-to-count-how-many-numbers-are-divisible-by-a-specific-integer-i)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O(1).

Something like this:

```
Math.floor((y-1) / k) - Math.floor((x-1) / k)
```

Explanation:

Math.floor((x-1) / k) is the number of numbers divisible by k before the interval.

Math.floor((y-1) / k) is the number of numbers divisible by k up to the end of the interval.

Should be right for positive numbers and k > 0. Hopefully ;)

Edit:
I see, you want to include y in the range. Ok, then change to:

```
Math.floor(y / k) - Math.floor((x-1) / k)
```

Is this for an assignment? I feel a little guilty.

Comment: `x=2; y=4; k=2`. Expected: 2, actual: 1

Comment: @zerkms, this is correct for a standard interpretation of "in the range between 2 and 4", which typically includes 2 but not 4. Other interpretations are possible, but you didn't specify one!

Comment: @senderle 1. I'm not an OP 2. OPs reference implementation represents a range as `[x; y]`